# I can't install Freya

Tags: release-freya

Yesterday I tried install the last version of Freya from DVD-R, but I can't install this OS by this message:

EDD: Error 3200 reading sector 422616

Invalid or corrupt kernel image.
boot:

Before (and later) this message appear a column of green text that tell this:

EDD: Error 3200 reading sector 423XXX
EDD: Error 3200 reading sector 423XXX
EDD: Error 3200 reading sector 423XXX
EDD: Error 3200 reading sector 423XXX..

(XXX = other numbers..)

Really I don't want try another install without know if my hardware is compatible with Freya.

Someone can tell me if my hardware it's compatible? (with Freya or other extension of Linux, like Ubuntu)

Motherboard: GIGABYTE GA-8SG667
2GB RAM
Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU (2.40 GHz)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your hardware appears to be compatible, but sounds like a corrupt file more than anything else. Could you verify the image you downloaded using the [installation docs](https://elementary.io/docs/installation), and possibly try another disk or verify that too? It could also be a physically damaged disk.

Comment: Hey. I've tried install Freya from my USB device, but... 

After of record .ISO file with Rufus (same configuration), I select USB-HDD from BIOS, then appears this message:

Verifying DMI Pool Data ........
SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 Copyright (C) 1994-2013 H. Peter Anvin et el
_

I've waited but never happened nothing... I tried also with other options (USB-ZIP/FDD...) but only loaded Windows.

What can I do now..?

Comment: Have you verified that the `.iso` file was downloaded completely?

Comment: Yes, isn't the first time I download Freya.

Comment: Sounds like the boot data isn't being set correctly. Rufus should be set exactly like this image, with ISO image selected on the drop-down. https://elementary.io/images/docs/installation/rufus_select_iso.png

Comment: I've followed the options that exactly appear in this image (I selected FAT23 instead of FAT, this option not appeared...)

I feel that is a hardware problem... but I don't know.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I am trying to install it from a 128GB usb stick, I never see installation process and I couldn't see FAT in Rufus (so I chose Large FAT). Could this be the problem @LewisGoddard?

Comment: Rufus likely won't offer FAT for a stick that large because Microsoft artificially limits it to 32 GB even though it can handle up to 16TB to promote NTFS. Try using NTFS instead and does it boot at all? Is the USB even listed in BIOS as a boot option?